# C file-reading loop always breaking

Tags: c, fopen, eof

Been looking in to C and I'm working on a simple program to read a text file, apply a caesar cipher, and write to a new output file. My problem is that the while-loop supposed to build my output string terminates immediately, claiming that the next character is EOF, even when it obviously isn't. Code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MORD ".mord"

void die(const char *message)
{
  if(errno) {
    perror(message);
  } else {
    printf("ERROR: %s\n", message);
  }

  exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if(argc != 3) die("USAGE: dodsmord <filename> <offset>");
  char *infilename = argv[1];
  char *outfilename = strcat(infilename, MORD);
  int offset = atoi(argv[2]);
  char *outstr[1000];
  FILE *infile = fopen(infilename, "r+");
  FILE *outfile = fopen(outfilename, "w+");
  if(infile == NULL) {
    die("Could not open input file");
  }
  if(outfile == NULL) {
    die("Could not open output file");
  }
  int c;
  int i = 0;
  printf("reading input file...\n");
  while(1) {
    c = fgetc(infile);
    printf("c == EOF: %d\n", c == EOF ? 1 : 0);
    printf("EOF: %d\n", EOF);
    printf("c is now: %c\n", c);
    if(c == EOF) break;
    outstr[i] = c + offset;
    i++;
  }
  printf("done reading! writing outstr to outfile...\n");
  fwrite(outstr, sizeof(char), i, outfile);

  printf("closing streams...\n");
  fclose(infile);
  fclose(outfile);

  return 0;
}
```

The output if I run the code on test.txt (which contains exactly "abcdefg" without quotes), I get the output

```
reading input file...
c == EOF: 1
EOF: -1
c is now: �
done reading! writing outstr to outfile...
closing streams...
```

Comment: You have declared variable `c` as `int` and using as `char`. why??

Comment: @Himanshu That's perfectly valid. In fact, the variable you use for the return of e.g. `fgetc` *must* be an `int` or weird things might happen when it returns `EOF`-

Comment: Have you checked that the input file actually have something in it? That its size is non-zero?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, you mean `c == EOF` is valid?? I don't think so.

Comment: @Himanshu Absolutely, that's how it's supposed to be used.

Comment: since the signature of fgetchar says it returns an int, that's what I used. I figured it wouldn't be a problem since from what I can tell, a char in C is basically just an int, albeit a bit smaller than the ints of most CPUs.

Comment: By the way, you have *undefined behavior* in your code. Your variable `outstr` is an array of *pointers* to characters, i.e. an array of strings. You also have some other serious problems in your code, like you appending another string to `argv[1]` which doesn't have enough allocated memory for it.

Comment: Terminate the outstr with null character before you write to the file , are you sure there is text in the input file ?

Comment: Since your code uses r+ mode for file opening, if it cannot find the file, it will create an empty one for you. Give absolute paths when you execute your binary.

Comment: thanks, joachim. fixed that now, which removed the last compiler warning.

Comment: @diegoperini absolute paths are not necessary; not changing the path before you use it is.

Comment: the txt exists and if I run cat test.txt I get the expected output (abcdefg). is this enough or should I check it out more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```
  char *infilename = argv[1];
  char *outfilename = strcat(infilename, MORD);
```

`strcat()` will change `infilename`, and append that `MORD` to the end of it, therefore you are using `argv[1].mord` as your input file name. I bet it is a empty file.

Solution:

Change

```
char *outfilename = strcat(infilename, MORD);
```

to

```
char *outfilename = malloc(strlen(infilename) + strlen(MORD) + 1);
if (outfilename == NULL) { /* malloc failed */ }
strcpy(outfilename, infilename);
strcat(outfilename, MORD);
```

Comment: Actually, `argv` is required to be modifiable as per C11 5.1.2.2.1/2: `The parameters argc and argv and the strings pointed to by the argv array shall be modifiable by the program, and retain their last-stored values between program startup and program termination`. I'd get rid of that paragraph in your answer.

Answer (score 9):

```
char *infilename = argv[1];
char *outfilename = strcat(infilename, MORD);
```

This doesn't do what you think it does.

It sets up `infilename` so that it points to the *same* memory as argv[1], then the `strcat` changes that memory to append the `.mord`.

Then it returns it so that `outfilename` *also* points to the memory.

Hence you're changing the input file name to be the `.mord` one and, when you try to open it, well, I don't know what will happen exactly, it depends on whether it exists yet.

What you want is something like:

```
char *infilename = argv[1];
char *outfilename = malloc (strlen (infilename) + strlen (MORD) + 1);
if (outfilename == NULL) {
    handleOutOfMemoryHere();
}
strcpy (outfilename, infilename);
strcat (outfilename, MORD);
:
// weave you cypher magic here
:
free (outfilename);
```

The second line in that code will give you a *separate* memory area for the output file name and the `strcpy/strcat` combo will construct it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by:

```
char *infilename = argv[1];
char *outfilename = strcat(infilename, MORD);
```

Reason: `strcat` does a in-place copy and returns the address of `src`. Try this and you would see:

```
char *infilename = argv[1];
char *outfilename = strcat(infilename, MORD);
printf("TEST: %p %p\n", infilename, outfilename);
```

To fix this, use something like this:

```
char *infilename = argv[1];
char *outfilename = malloc(strlen(infilename) + strlen(MORD) + 1);
strcpy(outfilenname, infilename);
strcat(outfilename, MORD);
```

Answer (score 1):

problem is with below line

```
char *outfilename = strcat(infilename, MORD);
```

infilename is getting modified to test.txt.mord

Move

```
FILE *infile = fopen(infilename, "r+");
```

above the following line

```
    char *outfilename = strcat(infilename, MORD);
```

Comment: note, `infilename` points to `argv[1]` which is read only, but `strcat` modifies it. you should copy its contents prior to `strcat`

Comment: Ok, but its limited size